# Strictly increasing function transformation

Tags: utility

I have utility function given by:

$U(x_1, x_2) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   x_1+x_2 & \text{if $x_1+x_2<6$} \\
                                   6 & \text{if $6\leq x_1+x_2\leq10$} \\
                                   x_1 + x_2 & \text{if $x_1+x_2>10$}
  \end{cases}$

If I transform this to this:

$F(U(x_1, x_2)) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   U(x_1, x_2)+4 & \text{if $U(x_1, x_2)<6$} \\
                                   10 & \text{if $U(x_1, x_2)=6$} \\
                                   U(x_1, x_2) & \text{if $U(x_1, x_2)>10$}
  \end{cases}$

Is it strictly increasing function transformation?

Thanks guys

Comment: Are you sure your definition makes sense? If I were you, I would first F alone, without reference to U.

Comment: @Arthur Why would that be helpful? Even from this formulation, one can see the problem.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I got it later its a non-decreasing function but not a strictly increasing one. @Arthur I wrote the function like that because it is more apparent rather than writing it without referring to U, anyways thanks for trying

Answer (score -2):

This is a strictly increasing monotonic transformation simply because the preferences in the previous function are the same in the transformed function as well.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.